# The Rubik Square permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, recreational-mathematics

This post was inspired by [this webpage](http://www.micmaths.com/defis/defi_07.html) of mathematical challenge due to [Mickaël Launay](http://www.micmaths.com/) (French).

Let $G_n$ be the subgroup of $S_{n^2}$ generated by the red arrow permutations as for the following picture with $n = 5$:
[image]
(*Source*: http://www.micmaths.com/defis/defi_07.html)

We can call $G_n$ the n-th Rubik Square permutation group.

**Question**: Is $G_n$ a strict subgroup of $S_{n^2}$?

Comment: The original challenge asks to put the grid in the rigth order $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, etc..., a case becomes orange if  it is the end of a rigth order, but this does not matter for the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us look at the commutator of the top row and leftmost column operations.
We easily see that the move sequence $\leftarrow\uparrow\rightarrow\downarrow$ is a 3-cycle involving the entries at positions $(1,1), (1,2), (2,1)$. Similarly for any other pair of rows and columns. Using appropriate powers of the elementary moves we get 3-cycles on any triple of positions $(i,j), (i,k), (\ell,j)$. A lot hinges on what we can say about the subgroup generated  by such 3-cycles.

I claim that such 3-cycles generate the alternating group $A_{n^2}$.
It suffices to prove that we get all the 3-cycles. The key observation is that any two 3-cycles $\in A_4$ generate all of $A_4$ unless they share a fixed point. This is because the generated subgroup is doubly transitive, and $A_4$ has no proper doubly transitive subgroups. What this means is that any pair of 3-cycles with an overlap of two positions gives us any 3-cycle among the four positions in the union.

So let $(i_t,j_t),t=1,2,3,$ be any three positions. The 3-cycles on
$(i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2),(i_2,j_1)$ and $(i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_1),(i_2,j_3)$ thus
generate the 3-cycles on $(i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2),(i_2,j_3)$. Together with the 3-cycles $(i_2,j_2),(i_2,j_3),(i_3,j_3)$ this then generates the desired 3-cycle.

Therefore $A_{n^2}\le G_n$.

If $n$ is odd, then all the generators of $G_n$ are in $A_{n^2}$, so we must have $G_n=A_{n^2}$. But if $n$ is even, then $G_n$ contains also odd permutations and we have $G_n=S_{n^2}$.

I won't say anything about the Cayley graph.

Comment: Sorry I was confusing in my post, when I asked "Is is transitive" I thought (but I didn't write) "on the set $S(\{ 1,2,3, \dots , n^2 \})$" and not on the set $\{ 1,2,3, \dots , n^2 \}$ (which is obvious). The transitivity on $S(\{ 1,2,3, \dots , n^2 \})$ is equivalent to $G_n = S_{n^2}$. I've edited the post.