# What's the asymptotic of the radius of the Rubik square Cayley graph?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory

This post is a sequel of [The Rubik Square permutation groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1341841/84284), which should be read first to understand the notation.

*Question*: what's the radius$^*$ of the Cayley graph of $G_n$ generated by the red arrows?

$^*$radius: the maximal distance in the Cayley graph from an element to the neutral element.